# MySQL Connection: Host 'x.y.z.z' is not allowed

Tags: mysql, connection

I'm trying to connect MySQL server(`192.168.1.102`) running `XAMPP 1.8.3(MySQL 5.6.16 GPL)` from the client machine(`192.168.1.108`) , but I get this error :

> `SQL Exception : null`, message from server : `Host '192.168.1.108'` is
>   not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

This is the connection code :

```
public Connection connect(String host) {
    try {                   
       String driver=textDriver.getText();
       // String host=textServer.getText();
       String db=textDatabase.getText();
       String user=textUser.getText();
       String pwd=txtPass.getText();       

       URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+ host +"/"+ db +"?user=" + user +"&password="+ pwd;

       Class.forName(driver);
       cn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
       connected=true;      

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Connection : " + cn.getCatalog(),
                                     "Database Connection",  
                                     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       return cn;
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Not Connected : " + e);   
       return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the main code(caller) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 127.0.0.1
    String host = "localhost"; 
    try {
        String client = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Is this client(y/n)", "y");
        if (client .equals("y") || client.equals("Y")) {
            // Client must connect to the server(192.168.1.102)                
            host = "192.168.1.102";    
        }            

        Conn = dialog.connect(host);
        if (dialog.connected == true)   {                        
            dialog.setVisible(false);
            dialog.dispose();    
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                                

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

Could anybody help me please ...

Comment: have you give user rights to your computer from server?

Comment: Since it is a SQL error this is not a pure networking issue. It looks more like a permission problem _inside_ mysql_, though the exact error message sounds unfamiliar to me. Check the granted access permissions in the internal "mysql" database, I'd say.